# Create a procedure for table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table named C_CASE
which is :

```
CREATE TABLE C_CASE
(
    Case_ID int,
    Case_Details varchar(255),
    Case_Status varchar(255),
    Section_Of_Law varchar(255)
);
```

The data in the table is:

```
Case_ID    Case_Details    Case_Status  Section_Of_Law
------------------------------------------------------
333         Hit and Run     Pending       304(A)
444         Robbery         Closed        392
555         Extortion       Pending       384
222         Murder          Closed        302
323         Murder          Pending       304(A)
123         Robbery         Pending       392
336         Extortion       Closed        384
567         Murder          Closed        302
```

My aim is to create a procedure that will output the number of pending and closed `Case_Statuses` for a particular `Case_Details`.

For example if the input is **MURDER**, then I want the output to be something as :

```
Pending      Closed
-------------------
   1           2
```

I am not getting the correct logic for this.

I am not good at SQL, I've tried a lot, I genuinely need help

My procedure code is :

```
 create procedure StatusCount
     @acc varchar(40)
 as 
     select 
         count(Case_Status) 
     from 
         C_Case 
     where 
         @acc = 'Pending' 
         and @acc = 'Closed'
 go

 drop procedure StatusCount

 exec StatusCount 'Robbery';
```

but I get no output, please help.

Comment: you are trying to execute a procedure right after you drop it. Also, `where @acc='Pending' and @acc='Closed'` will never satisfy anything.

Comment: I know I am wrong, Can you please tell me what should be the logic behing it.

Answer (score 1):

So couple of mistakes..

**One:** you dropped the procedure before execution. **Two:** the query is wrong

```
create procedure StatusCount (@acc varchar(40))
as 
begin
    select 
        sum(case when Case_Status = 'Pending' then 1 else 0 end) Pending, 
        sum(case when Case_Status = 'Closed' then 1 else 0 end) Closed -- removed comma, there was an extra comma causing syntax issue
    from 
        C_Case 
    where 
        Case_Details = @acc
end
go

exec StatusCount 'Robbery'; 
--drop below proc

drop procedure StatusCount`
```

Explanation for query:

We need data for a particular type of `Case_Details`, so

```
where Case_Details = @acc
```

And we need to count `Pending` and `Closed` cases in a single line, so we do a `sum()` over all rows

But we need to count a row only when case_status is a match, so a `case when then end` logic like for counting pending cases

```
sum(case when Case_Status = 'Pending' then 1 else 0 end) Pending
```

which literally means sum all row's value based on the inner case expression result which gives 1 only when status is Pending otherwise 0.. so we net count all pending rows

Comment: I didn't get the logic. Care to explain ? P.S : I EXECUTED YOUR CODE AND IT GAVE ME "INCORRECT SYNTAX NEAR KEYWORD FROM"

Comment: That helped man! Thanks a ton. So Now I need to work a bit more on logic and basics. Thank you.